# Sailfish: how to run on computer without gpu

Tags: python, opencl, gpu

Is there a way to run [`sailfish`](http://code.google.com/p/sailfish-cfd/) on a system without **GPU**?
Attempts so far: `PyOpenCL` works OK. However none of the examples from `sailfish` can be run properly!

Error appears in `sailfish` `backend_opencl.py`:

```
...
devices = platform.get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.GPU)
RuntimeError: clGetDeviceIDs failed device not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the target device type is hardcoded as GPU.

You could try to change their code with something like :

```
platform.get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.ALL)
```

It will lookup for any device : GPU, CPU, accelerator.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted and am going to accept your answer because it solved the device problem reporting Using the "opencl" backend. However, all provided example codes fail to run with other problems in `Preparing compute device code.`; Any advice?

Comment: BTW, if you know some basic `LBM` code in `Python` please provide us the links. Google was not helpful so far!

Comment: Could you please give more information about the error? If the issue is unrelated to this one you should open a new question as it will speedup resolution and ease future retrieval as SO promotes a question/answer format. :)

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. None of the codes run. `Traceback (most recent call last): ... mako.exceptions.TemplatelookupException: Cant locate template for uri u'sailfish/propagation.mako`. I am looking for a simple `LBM` code in `Python` now stuck with countless problems in sailfish!

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the sample is not up-to-date; have you tried "sailfish/templates/propagation.mako"? If it does not work either try to locate the needed file on your install and adapt the code that is searching for them providing the correct paths. Anyway it seems like you'll have to update the code to fit your current install. :(

Comment: Well, the way I solved the `mako` problem is that I copied all `mako` files from `templates` directory to one-up-level `sailfish` directory. Luckily the codes run now, although surprisingly very slow!